# React Native - Navigation fail

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to switch between components using the `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/native-stack` packages. I've followed the suggested way of doing this (using this article here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) but I'm running into an error. I've used the expo CLI to generate this project, just for context.

The error reads:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Registration"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

It also suggests I check out this page here for a solution:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

I've taken a look at the page, but this just seems like a tangled mess and I'm not sure how to reconcile the way the first article and second article are suggesting that this be done.

Can someone take a look at this code and make any suggestions for how I might achieve my goal of swapping between components using the provided navigation modules?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import EditScreenInfo from '../../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text  } from '../../components/Themed';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Constants } from '../../constants/Constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function TabOneScreen() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{title: 'Login'}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegistrationScreen} options={{title: 'Register'}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)};

const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null)
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null)

  const subdomain = Constants.Subdomain;

  const onPressLogin = async () => {
    console.log('email', email);
    console.log('password', password);

    var req_json = { Email: email, Password: password};

    console.log(req_json);

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          //"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    //await axios.get('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/Account/Login/?email=' + email + "&password=" + password);

    // acquire token, set that in javascript as a cookie/save it globally and refer to it
    var req_json2 = {username: email, password: password, grant_type: 'password'}

    var headers2 = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          //"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    const resp = await axios.post('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/token', req_json2, headers2);
    
    const token = resp.data.access_token;

    console.log("auth_token: " + token);

    AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_token', token);

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputText}
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress = {onPressLogin}
        style={styles.loginBtn}>
        <Text>Log in.</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Registration')}
        style={styles.registerBtn}
        title='Register'
      />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const RegistrationScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
  return <Text>Register New User.</Text>;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"white"
  },
  loginBtn: {
    
  },
  registerBtn: {
    marginTop:35
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth:2,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    marginTop: 15,
    color:'black'
  }
});
```

I tried to implement navigation using the provided react-native navigation packages but it isn't working. Also, the Register button/link is not rendering. No clue why.

Comment: Your screen name should be **Register**. Please use `navigation.navigate('Register')` instead.